# IronPython for python 3 or something similar

Tags: python, user-interface, ironpython

i downloaded visual studios lately and i wanted to use IronPython GUI designer to make a good looking GUI with a designer instead of writing tkinter code. But my issue is that i can only write python3 code and IronPython is Python 2.7 so i dont know about any other that let me use a designer. I know i can use tkinter or Qt and i have before but i feel that they take too much to fix when i could just use a designer instead. So my question would be if there is a IronPython version for Python 3.x or something else i can use?

Comment: http://www.python4.net

Comment: @denfromufa i need a designer like C# windows forms

Comment: Here is how to workaround this currently: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1156